# angularJS: how to use setTimeout?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
function performerController($scope, $http) {
    this.getPerformerOnline = function (performerid) {
        setTimeout(this.getPerformerOnline, 3000, performerid);
        $http.get("ajax.php", {
            params:{
                "action":"getPerformerOnline", "performerid":performerid
            }
        }).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.performer = data;
        });         
    };  
    this.getPerformerOnline(<?=$user->id?>);    
}
```

This function is called TWICE only : console.log(data); displays 2 times result.

How to call the getPerformerOnline each 3000ms ?

Comment: Use [$interval service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval).

Comment: Set an interval rather than having the function set a timeout each time it is called.

Answer (score 4):

You need an [`$interval`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$interval) and not a timeout, also avoid using `setTimeout` in angular and instead use angulars [`$timeout`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$timeout) service...

```
function performerController($scope, $http, $interval) {
    this.getPerformerOnline = function (performerid) {
        $interval(this.getPerformerOnline, 3000, performerid);
        $http.get("ajax.php", {
            params:{
                "action":"getPerformerOnline", "performerid":performerid
            }
        }).success(function(data) {
            console.log(data);
            $scope.performer = data;
        });         
    };  
    this.getPerformerOnline(<?=$user->id?>);    
}
```

Comment: I could be wrong but, every time you run the getPerformerOnline function it's going to set up another interval. The number of listeners will double every three seconds.

Answer (score 1):

Don't set a timeout in the funtion itself. Instead define your function, then use the `$interval` service to call it repeatedly.

```
function performerController($scope, $http, $interval) {
  this.getPerformerOnline = function (performerid) {
    $http.get("ajax.php", {
      params:{
        "action":"getPerformerOnline", "performerid":performerid
      }
    }).success(function(data) {
      console.log(data);
      $scope.performer = data;
    });         
  };  
  $interval(this.getPerformerOnline, 3000, performerid);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use $interval.
The advantage of using $interval service is, it call $digest cycle internally.

```
function MainController($scope, $interval) {
    $scope.intervalFunction = function(){
      //your code goes here 
    }
    var intervalPromise = $interval(function () { $scope.intervalFunction() }, 5000);  

    //best practice destroying the $interval on scope destroy
    $scope.$on('$destroy', function () { $interval.cancel(intervalPromise); });
}
```

Hope this will help you.